# AMP errors in web master tool

Tags: google-search-console, amp-html

I have implemented AMP successfully for my webpages and google started indexing it, which I came to know via WebMaster tool. I am facing some issues which is present and disappears in short span of time. 
Issue logged are:

1. User authored JavaScript found on page
   The pages doesn't contain any script tags except schema. 
   This error is showing for few pages from 120 pages instead of following same

template. Below is the image link:

[image]

Have some more query:

1. I have observe different amp urls getting redirected to its original page when the same amp url is being used in Web Browser.
   Is Google taking care of it or its on us to do the redirection?
2. I am planning to implement the sign in and share buttons on my web pages which will be using javascript. But if I do so, I do get validation error. So what is the right approach.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please ensure that all script tags are of type `application/ld+json`. There should be no executable code in these script tags.
2. Redirection is something that you must be doing on your end. Google doesn't do any sort of redirection from AMP to non-amp pages if the URL is hit directly. In fact that URL schema that Google uses in their carousel is entirely their own, and just includes the path to your page inside it. E.g. https://cdn.ampproject.org/v/www.yoursitehere.com/path/to/article.html
3. Social sharing using Javascript inserted in the page is not allowed, as no Javascript is allowed. If you want to use social sharing, use a non-javascript implemention, or try out the [amp-social-share](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-social-share.html)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the response. As per the query which I asked

1. Please ensure that all script tags are of type application/ld+json. There should be no executable code in these script tags - **I am not using any Script as of now except amp only**
2. Redirection is something that you must be doing on your end. Google doesn't do any sort of redirection from AMP to non-amp pages if the URL is hit directly. In fact that URL schema that Google uses in their carousel is entirely their own, and just includes the path to your page inside it. E.g. https://cdn.ampproject.org/v/www.yoursitehere.com/path/to/article.html - 
   **Understood**
3. Social sharing using Javascript inserted in the page is not allowed, as no Javascript is allowed. If you want to use social sharing, use a non-javascript implementation, or try out the amp-social-share - **Implemented Social Share and its working fine**

Can we implement AMP for eCommerce sites where a lot of JavaScript, forms, plugins can be included? As of my knowledge AMP wants to keep it simple and thus restrict as many JavaScript, form tag is not valid only. So is there any chance we can implement AMP on eCommerce sites.

Comment: Parvez, I would recommend you do a little more research on what sort of website AMP is meant for on the www.ampproject.org website. That being said, your page speed will improve if you try and follow the AMP guidelines as close as possible.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Kempf

Comment: if this answered your question, please click on the checkmark next to my answer to accept it. Welcome to Stack Overflow!